# Is there a way to only activate the cancel button on a search bar while editing?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I know you can do this with the clear button on a text field like this:

```swift
searchController?.searchBar.searchTextField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing
```

But is there something similar for the cancel button on a search bar?

```swift
searchController?.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true // this exists
searchController?.searchBar.cancelButtonMode = .whileEditing // I could not find this
```

[image: Cancel Button]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the search bar to appear until the user actually taps on the search bar of the search controller, don't add any code for the cancel button. The default behavior is to not show the cancel button until the user activates search.

Simply remove any code you have to setup or change the cancel button.

As of iOS 13 you can use the `automaticallyShowsCancelButton` property of `UISearchController` but in iOS it defaults to `true`. It seems to default to `false` under Mac Catalyst.

Answer (score 2):

No, There is no direct method like you mentioned but you can do it by its delegate methods.

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
}
```

These are methods when Search textfield is editing and end editing. This will perfectly serve your purpose.

Comment: Easy, very straightforward solution.